# Efficiently Handling a ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to fetch the results from a database using jdbc connectivity. My result set is made of more than 60,000 rows which I'm then iterating to build a list for comparison with another list object of similar size. Problem is that while this approach gives the correct result, it's very slow. Any ideas as two how to speed it up ? The code sample is given below:

```
public class PerformanceTest {

    //create a connection
    Connection getConnection(String uName, String pwd, String url) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.setProperty("user", uName);
        info.setProperty("password", pwd);
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
           throw e;
        }
    }

    //Fetch the records and put them in a map with schema name as key and table name as value
    public List<String> fetchRecords(Connection conn, String sql) throws SQLException
    {
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        String tableName;
        List<String> tableList;
        long startTime;
        int i=0;
        if(conn!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                tableList = new ArrayList<String>();
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(++i);
                    tableName = rs.getString(1);
                    tableList.add(tableName);
                }

                System.out.println("Running Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000 + " seconds");
                return tableList;
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
     }

    public boolean main() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx:1521:xxxxx";
        Connection conn = getConnection("", "", url);
        String sql = "SELECT  table_name FROM user_tables";
        long startTime;
        boolean result;
        List<String> l1 = fetchRecords(conn, sql);
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>(l1);
        //l2.add("1");
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = l2.containsAll(l1);
        System.out.println("Running Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000 + " seconds");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please quantify 'very slow'

Comment: The code in your `main()` function (shouldn't use that as your own function's name by the way) isn't testing the duration of the database operation, it's testing how long it takes you to compare the contents of the two list. Which are always the same, given that `l2` is constructed as a copy of `l1`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Btw, never `catch` an exception if all you're going to do is just re-throw it and nothing else. This screws up the stack trace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel slows is 502 seconds to build the list.

Comment: @musical_coder please take a look at fetchRecords method. It's the runtime in that method which I'm concerned about.

Comment: Thus the delay is in the `while` loop? How long does the `executeQuery` take?

Comment: @Meesh executeQuery is sufficiently fast. Less than a second it takes.

Comment: What is the query time if you execute that same query in - for example - SQL*Plus (or another query tool)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think the real overhead is not in executing the query, but in building the list by iterating over the result set.

Comment: @musical_coder In Java the stacktrace isn't changed by catching and throwing, maybe you are thinking of C#?

Comment: Very strange! Remove the sysout, and perhaps squash two lines into one `tableList.add(rs.getString(1))` ?

Comment: @Parminder Not necessarily, and even then comparing with a totally different tool may help identify the actual bottleneck. What SQL*Plus does is not that different than what is done here (iterating over a resultset).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: you're right, I was thinking of C#. Still, it doesn't make a lot of sense to do it like it's being done above. Nothing wrong with declaring that your function `throws` a particular exception (especially since this code already has that).

Comment: @Parminder: ah, I see where you're talking about. I agree with Meesh about removing the `println` and consolidating the two lines. You should also try `rs.getString("myColumnName")` instead of retrieving by index number. See if that improves performance at all.

Comment: Try `stmt = conn.createStatement(); stmt.setFetchSize(100);` this will reduce a number of database round-trips (a default value is 10 for Oracle JDBC driver)

Comment: @musical_coder thanks. I was able cut it down to 238 seconds from 502 to using add(rs.getString(1)).

Comment: @kordirko Thanks man! down to 6 seconds!

Comment: @kordirko You should post that as the answer; the fetch size was definitely key.